# Watson Conversation: multi-language website approach

Tags: watson-conversation

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to interfacing with Watson Conversation from a multi-language website (English/French). The input to Watson Conversation will be fed from Watson STT, so the input should be in the appropriate language. Should I set up the intents and entities in both languages? That might potentially cause issues with words that are the same (or very similar) in both languages but have different meanings. My guess is that I'll need two separate Conversation workspaces but that seems like a lot of overhead (double work when anything changes). I've thought about using the Watson Language Translator in between STT and Conversation but I would think the risk with that approach could be a reduction in accuracy.  Has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set up separate workspaces for each language. As you need to set the language of your workspace.

After that you would need to do STT, then language detection service to determine what workspace it should be directed to.

Comment: Thanks, Simon, I thought that would likely be the answer.  I'm not sure, though, what you mean by "language detection service"?  Is that a separate Watson service?  The STT output is sent to the Conversation service via a Spring app and the Locale is included in the method call, so I don't think I'll need another service to determine the language unless I'm missing something.

Comment: There is a "Language Translator" service. One of it's functions is to detect language from text. But if you already know the locale, I would use that as it would work out cheaper and easier.

Comment: Simon - you answered my question before I had a chance to finish editing it. :)